# Accents and tilde on Firefox are not above letters

Tags: firefox

I've recently installed Kubuntu 14.04 64bits on my Aspire 4752, where I had a Lubuntu 14.04 with `/home` partition.

Everything works fine, and I can type Portuguese accents and tildes on other programs, including Chrome, but in Firefox, when I type an accent, it appears before the letter, so when I type the vowel, they are not together, like á, but like ´a.

The ç, however, is working fine (majority of internet complains about Firefox and keyboard problems are about ç).
Tried different Firefox extensions to type diacritics, and followed all Google tutorials, but couldn't solve it.

Is there some way to solve this problem?

Edit: now I noticed that google chrome does it some times, but if I close it and open, it may do it or not randomly.

Comment: I have only the file ~/xinputrc and in /etc/X11/xinit/ there is not folder /xinput.d.

Answer (score 0):

Someone having a similar problem could solve it by removing a symlink to a system config directory:

He had a link `~/.xinput.d` pointing to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/scim`,
and fixed the problem by removing it, so try removing it if you have that link. (maybe renaming first)

See [Thread: [SOLVED] dead keys not working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=798426&p=4986097#post4986097)

Comment: I tried everything on internet, and cold solve it just by reinstalling Kubuntu, and formating the /home partition. Aparently, there were some settings from my old Distro that were affecting Kubuntu's behavior.